# technical considerations for including an extraneous javascript library in a Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, benchmarking, handlebars.js

I recently included Handlebars.js in a rails project, and a coworker balked at the notion. What are the realistic technical considerations when including an extra javascript library into a rails project?

Does the addition of an extraneous library significantly slow down the site delivery and user experience? Is this an example of engineering drama?

Has this been measured?

Comment: The real question is whether using something like Handlebars represents an architectural shift that may or may not be compatible with your organization and its strategy.

Comment: What @Pointy said. Handlebars is a significant change to your front-end architecture as well as how you'll be binding data received from the backend. As far as load times, it's a pretty minuscule addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding additional libraries slows down the site delivery by several hundred milliseconds. It also requires some client time to parse and run its onload()-type functionality. From a human standpoint, it requires a bit of time to get used to using the new library. Depending on the level of complexity, usefulness, and time-saving of the library, this may be an acceptable tradeoff.

Handlebars is a great tool for templating, but you really need everybody on your team to be on board to use it. It's not very nice to simply introduce a brand new way of doing things without really discussing things. Handlebars is a big enough change to warrant at least a discussion, if not a vote.

If you were just wanting to put it there to see if it would work in the future, or maybe just convert over a page or two, then you should do that in a separate branch and do a quick prototype and demo for the team.

Depending on whether there is a valid business case and legitimate usefulness, you and the team can decide whether to convert your application to use it.